# NGRX Store adapter.updateone not changing properties for change detection

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have the following reducer:

```
case ProductionCommentActionTypes.EditCommentSuccess: {
  return adapter.updateOne(action.payload, state);
}
```

where the payload is the following object:

```
{ 
    id: number,
    changes: { 
       id: number;
       avatar: string;
       createdAt: Date;
       createdBy: string;
       body: string;
       discipline: string;
       isConcern: boolean;
       isResolved: boolean;
       plan_Id: number;
       resolution: {
                    id: number;
                    comment_Id: number;
                    avatar: string;
                    createdAt: Date;
                    createdBy: string;
                    body: string;   
                   }
      }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I go to update the object, I can plainly see action.payload has exactly the data im annticipating. Ive checked both action.payload, and the effect:

```
  @Effect()
  resolveProductionConcernSuccess$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType<ResolveConcernSuccess>(ProductionCommentActionTypes.ResolveConcernSuccess).pipe(
    // Performing a get rather than an edit as the comment should have already 
    // been updated in the service when the resolution was added.
    switchMap(action => this.commentService.getComment(action.payload.comment_Id)), 
          map((comment: any) => {
            comment.updatedBy = "test";
        return new EditCommentSuccess(comment);
      }),
    catchError(err => of(new EditCommentFail(err)))
  );
```

However, what i see from this:

```
  this.comments$ = rootStore.select<Comment[]>(fromRoot.getCommentsForSelectedPlan);
this.comments$.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Is the old data, even though a change is triggered. I would have at least expected to see updatedBy = "test". I also see the old data on state *immediately after* the updateOne if i step through in the debugger.

Another way to say it is

```
      return adapter.updateOne(action.payload, state);
```

Doesn't seem to actually change anything despite having the correct values in the payload.

***Why are the properties on the state not actually updated? Is there a proper way to do that?***

Comment: if caching is enabled on your browser, you may see old data

Comment: By old data i mean immediately old data, like right before the update.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was in the reducer.

```js
return adapter.updateOne({
  id: action.payload.id,
  changes: action.payload
},
  state);
```